# javascript button click and asp.net button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, buttonclick

I want to click a button (ASP.net) - which needs to run a JS method and if its true, then it has to call the ASP.Net - 
ie.,  i hv a form, and if its validated(JS returning true) in the client side - then only my asp.net button -click event must fire.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run something only on one response, use @Cybernate's example but modified:

```
<asp:Button ...  OnClientClick="if (yourValidationMethod() == false) return false;" />
```

If invalid, the return false would block the postback, otherwise normal postback happens.

Comment: in what way it is different from the  <asp:Button ...  OnClientClick="return yourValidationMethod()" /> ?? Just curious to know as im new to JS !

Comment: OK, after the client click code, there is either a __doPostBack or WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions call that actually triggers the postback to the server.  Just doing return yourValidationmethod(); will never allow the postback when the validation succeeds.  Exiting the routine only when false, as I have, will only block the postback when invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Try OnClientClick attribute of asp:Button i.e.

```
<asp:Button ...  OnClientClick="return yourValidationMethod()" />
```

Make sure that your validation method returns true or false based on the validation.

Answer (score 1):

Use OnClientClick property for ASP.NET button. Return false if validation failed, return true if it succeeded.

Comment: Thanks Pal. I know OnClientClick - but didnt know these days this has a nice effect !!  what a lame guy im !!